# how to specify include and exclude url patterns together in a pageMod?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I want my pageMod to load for all pages except a particular domain(s).

currently i have specified

`include:['*']` in the pageMod that loads it for all urls.

how can i make it avoid particular domains such as www.example.com and load for the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'exclude' property for page-mod ( and after some fiddling I could not get negative lookahead assertions to work well ), so I expect the best route might be to use the tabs module instead:

```
var tabs = require('tabs');

tabs.on('open', function(tab) {
    // some url exclusion logic?
    if (tab.url.indexOf('http://example.com') !== -1) {
        tab.on('ready', function(tab) {
            let worker = tab.attach({
                contentScriptfile: data.url('somefile.js')
            });

            worker.on('event', function(message) {
                //...
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: you can also use worker.tab.url within the PageMod's onAttach function to filter pages